# Catching OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, out-of-memory

Is there any point catching an out of memory error (`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`) in Java?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes**. Here are a few examples where it could make sense:

- if you want to handle it by **gracefully closing** your program
- if you want to display the problem to the user or **log the error**
- depending on your design, you might even be able to clear up memory and **restore a working state**

*However*, note that normally (unless you're at a spot where you'll be allocating tons of memory at once), you probably wouldn't specifically catch OutOfMemoryError for these cases, but rather do a `catch Throwable` all the way at the top in your main entry point.

Comment: True, but you do that in a finally block, not in a catch block

Comment: @Sean, Thats not a good idea as the finally block will only result in the exit of one thread, for you to have a graceful shutdown you may need to save your work and exit() the program.

Answer (score 11):

The golden rule is to only catch errors that you can handle. If you can do something useful after an OutOfMemory error, then go ahead.

Answer (score 7):

No, catch `Exception` and `RuntimeException`, but hardly ever (changed from 'never') [`Error`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html):

> An Error is a subclass of `Throwable`
>   that indicates serious problems **that a
>   reasonable application should not try
>   to catch**. Most such errors are
>   abnormal conditions. The `ThreadDeath`
>   error, though a "normal" condition, is
>   also a subclass of `Error` because most
>   applications should not try to catch
>   it.

**Note:**
I'm quoting the official Javadocs here. If you don't agree, tell Oracle, don't shoot the messenger :-)

Comment: It's preferred to catch errors in development/testing and deal with them. For memory you can increase memory available to the VM, but obviously you sometimes have to restructure your application to use less memory at some point.

Comment: disagree out of principle with the "Never". :)

Comment: @Epaga fair enough, changed that

Comment: "
should not try to catch" and "must not catch" are 2 totally different things.

Comment: @Pacerier which is why I changed my answer.

Answer (score 5):

As some other answers have pointed out, it is a **bad idea** to catch `OutOfMemoryError` and attempt to recover<sup>1</sup>.  Rather than just repeating that the javadoc says you `Error` exceptions are not recoverable, I'll try to explain why.

In fact there are at least two solid reasons why OOME recovery is unwise:

---

The First Reason is that OOME's are *typically* the result of undiagnosed memory leaks.  If your application catches and attempts to recover, the chances are that the leaked memory will still be reachable and hence still won't be reclaimed.  So when your application starts doing things it is likely to leak more memory ... and run into another OOME.  Sooner or later, the application grinds to a halt.

Since there is no way you can be absolutely sure that your application doesn't leak, OOME recovery is never going to be a solid, reliable answer.

---

The Second Reason is that when an OOME occurs, there is a chance that it will do damage to the execution state.  It might cause threads to terminate, leaving other threads waiting for notifications that will never arrive, etc.  It might occur in the middle of updating a critical application data structure or (possibly worse) a JVM data structure.  If your application then attempts to recover, it might lock up, or (worse) it might manage to keep going with corrupted data, and produce unpredictable results.

Unless you perform a forensic analysis of your codebase, you can never be entirely sure that this kind of thing won't happen.

---

I won't say you should NEVER attempt to recover from an OOME, but in general it is a risky thing to do.  And the more complex your application is, the harder it is to evaluate the risk.

---

<sup>1 - Here I am talking about catching OOME in an attempt to allow the application to continue running as before; i.e. to recover the application.  Catching an OOME in order to perform (or trigger) an orderly shutdown is a different matter.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a graceful shutdown which handles this case specificly.

You can also use it if you may have to allocate a large array and you want to gracefully degrade your system.

EDIT: An example of code where I used to check OOM if the stream was corrupted. I have since replace the len check to ensure the len is between 0 and 16 MB instead.

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

public byte[] readBytes() {
  int len = dis.readInt();
  try {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
    dis.readFully(bytes);
    return bytes;
  } catch(OutOfMemoryError e) {
    log.error("Corrupt stream of len="+len);
    closeSocket();
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: You really wont be able to gracefully degrade your system as the JVM itself would have crashed.

Comment: When the system crashes with a crash dump there is nothing you can do in Java.  However if all you get is an OutOfMemoryError, you can catch this and allow your system to keep running. There is nothing in this error which forces your system to crash.

Comment: @Peter : Out of curiosity - if you get a OOM which means that there is no longer any space in the heap to assign to objects and the GC is also fails to create any free space then where would your objects be created and how would your program run?

Comment: If you try to create an array or image or block of text which is far too large it will fail outright (might not even trigger a GC)  This will result in an OOM even if you happen to have many MB free (because you don't have enough free memory to create this large object)  For a graceful shutdown when you haven't created large objects, you create a 1 MB byte[] which you clear only when shutting down.

Comment: 2My take on this is that this does not seem to be the right way to develop java code. One of the biggest differences between java and C is that you do not have to handle memory in java. You do not have to know  how much memory each and every object will take(unless you may be writing J2ME code). So using the above approach you will have to do things that you can mitigate by 1) following best practices 2) profiling your code and finding memory leaks 3) adding jvm args

Comment: I agree, you shouldn't do this as a general practice. But there are situations where you know you could run out of memory loading data which may be user driven and you want to be able to say to the user, sorry I cannot load this data in an elegant way with minimal impact to anything else you might be doing.  Crashing with no indication to the user what the matter is and lossing all their work is not always the best approach to take.

Answer (score 2):

This has already been mentioned a number of times, but the replies indicate a few people are confused about this (common) recovery technique for an `OutOfMemoryError`.  Check my post to [What if new fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785343/what-if-new-fails/4786461#4786461) for a demo of how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The only place I have done that was mobile development. You can ask user to close other applications in order to give your application ability to work properly. But that's not the case of Android development.

I don't see any other things you can do with the situation. May be, some appropriate logging or cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an exception; it's an error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

You can catch it as it descends from Throwable:

> try {
>
> // create lots of objects here and stash them somewhere
>
> } catch (OutOfMemoryError E) {
>
> // release some (all) of the above objects
>
> }

However, unless you're doing some rather specific stuff (allocating tons of things within a specific code section, for example) you likely won't be able to catch it as you won't know where it's going to be thrown from.

Comment: Using Soft/WeakReferences is a better way to release objects in the event of low memory. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the errors you should never catch. The reason for this is simple you will not be able to do anything about it at runtime. However if your application is regularly facing this error then you should consider the following strategies to mitigate this issue-

1. Increase the memory available to the JVM by adding jvm args

> -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m

1. If the errors still persist then use a profiler like JProfiler or a Eclipse MAT to analyze how much memory your application uses.
2. Move to a 64 bit system and increase the JVM memory even further.