# Sandboxing and monitoring of Akka actors

Tags: java, scala, jvm, akka

I want to run several of my simple REST applications in one Akka actor system to save memory and scale them all in a simple way. Can I prevent them from each other and be sure that none of them could crash entire system? Can I prevent system from blocking threads and infinite memory consumption in any of my application logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you ask for is impossible on the JVM.

Comment: Thanks, Viktor. Sad to hear this.

Comment: Why sad? There's nothing you can do to prevent another program from shutting down the computer...

Comment: So what about custom class loaders, security manager or layer of abstraction as Rhino for example? This case can't be handled somehow?

Comment: Or can't I analyze bytecode before running as in Google Native Client?

Comment: Akka is all about letting it crash, you do not get fault tolerance by never failing, but always have something to fall back on.

Comment: I know about JVM almost nothing, but maybe I could catch OOME and crash particular request handler in controlled manner? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403972/out-of-memory-error)

Comment: I also wonder if it's possible to detect potential long-locks (pinging worker actor?) and deal with it in controlled manner. Particular requests could be roughly killed if do something stupid, but I'd like to avoid influence on another production apps and their end-user experience. I assume that crash of entire node from time to time is o.k. until I deploy request handler which can crash entire node via single http request.

Comment: Catching OOME is a very bad idea. In fact so bad that there's a JVM setting to forcefully crash the JVM if it happens.
I recommend using backup/load-balancing multiple machines instead of trying to avoid failure that that extent.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, Viktor. They are very helpful for me. I directed my research from prevention to monitoring now. I realized that all available informations about living JVM are in java.lang.management package. Is it true?