# Load images error

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio

I need to load a generated image into my Java desktop application.

I am using similar code than this:

```
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("strawberry.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
//it isn't the code here
}
```

The image it is loaded, but at bigger images my application just quit.

What to do to detect how big image can I load, or not just quit?

Comment: So, this image loads but larger images don't? How big are these larger images? What's the file size? What's the actual error message you're getting? Is it an IOException (file too big?) or is it because you're running out of memory? Please include the exception that causes the app to quit.

Comment: well a few megabyte pictures are loading. Others depends, if it is around 50-100 MB not always.

Comment: Sounds like a memory exhaustion problem. Try raising the heap memory limit, e.g. using the `-Xmx` switch of OpenJDK, e.g. `-Xmx1500m` for 1.5GiB of memory. Notice that a `BufferedImage` is uncompressed and may therefore be a lot larger than the file storing the image. 4 bytes per pixel is common.

Comment: I believe the default amount of RAM that the JVM will take (unless you change it via @MvG's suggestion, is 64MB. So anything close to or over that size would definitely crash your app.

Comment: `} catch (IOException e) {
//it isn't the code here
}`  Maybe not, but the code there should include `e.printStackTrace()` same for every catch in broken code you are asking us about.

Comment: @AndrewThompson +1 for `e.printStackTrace()`. I just want to add that this is helpful for debugging but not very helpful to the end-user in production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't in an Event Dispatcher Thread ( like when a button in UI is pressed ) than your app will not crash. It will crash the Thread, which will be deallocated, you will not get the image but your app will be alive.

There is is possibility to create a Thread: or you will extend  a Thread and override the run() method or create a Runnable interface and give it to a thread constructor.

```
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("strawberry.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
//it isn't the code here
}catch(OutOfMemoryError err){
// your code will be here :)
}
```

Try to debug / log your code before enter in loading images function to see how much is your maximum allocable memory:

```
// Get current size of heap in bytes
long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();

// Get maximum size of heap in bytes. The heap cannot grow beyond this size.
// Any attempt will result in an OutOfMemoryException.
long heapMaxSize = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();

// Get amount of free memory within the heap in bytes. This size will increase
// after garbage collection and decrease as new objects are created.
long heapFreeSize = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

If you have 50 MB free and the file is 50MB, than no reason to try to load.

Answer (score 1):

> What to do to detect how big image can I load, or not just quit?

There might be libraries that allow you to determine the WxH and color depth of images by reading the header, but nothing in the J2SE will do it out of the box.

Another approach 'from the other direction' is to take a defensive approach to loading them.  This technique is outlined in code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4786461/418556) but can be summarized as:

- reserve a buffer of memory
- prepare a memory warning panel in advance
- do the 'memory intensive' task
- on `OutOfMemoryError`: provide the VM with some memory 'breathing space' by clearing the buffer
- tell the user what went wrong, and how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Java programs have a maximum amount of memory they can use.
I believe the maximum size is around 128MB.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: maybe this is the problem, is there any way to let me know runtime about my current file limit, which I can load without crash?

Comment: @user1657239, you can determine the current memory limit, but you won't know up front the uncompressed size of a compressed image like jpeg. Not without manually examining the image header, I believe.

Comment: This answer isn't correct. You simply tell the JVM to increase the amount of memory you want. There's a default limit, but there's no maximum - you can tell the JVM to use gigabytes and gigabytes of memory.

Comment: This answer is still correct, he wanted to know why it didn't load the picture. And this is why.

Comment: @normalocity *"there's no maximum"*  This comment is incorrect.